# Error implementing a stoplimit order in quantstrat

Tags: r, quantstrat, blotter

After adding `ordertype=stoplimit` rules for  stoploss implementation in quantstrat's pair_trade.R demo (only the short side shown below) as,

```
# stop loss for short order (child)
add.rule(strategy=pairStrat, name = 'ruleSignal', arguments=list(sigcol='short',
    sigval=TRUE,
    replace=FALSE, 
    orderside='short', 
    ordertype='stoplimit', 
    tmult=TRUE, 
    prefer='Close',
    TxnFees='TxnCost',
    threshold=quote(.stoplossPercent), 
    orderqty='all', 
    orderset='ocoshort'),
type='chain', parent='Enter_Short',
label='StopLoss_Short',
enabled=FALSE)
```

and enabling it via:

```
enable.rule(pairStrat,'chain',"StopLoss_Long","StopLoss_Short")
```

I get the error:

```
Error in if (grepl(label, strategy$rules[[type]][[i]]$label)) strategy$rules[[type]][[i]]$enabled <- enabled :
  argument is of length zero
```

A very similar approach was nevertheless successful with a single instrument portfolio strategy.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I can't replicate this error.  Are you assigning the output of `add.rule` and `enable.rule` back to `pairStrat`?

Comment: I am not certain I understand your question. I do know that pairStrat is my strategy object defined as: `pairStrat <- strategy('pairStrat')
`.  The full code of the modified demo is on `https://bitbucket.org/marital_weeping/pair_trade-modified`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [bitbucket code](https://bitbucket.org/marital_weeping/pair_trade-modified) runs for me if I assign the output of `add.rule` and `enable.rule` back to `pairStrat` (as is done for all the other `add.rule` calls in the demo).

```
# wrong
add.rule(strategy=pairStrat, ...)
enable.rule(pairStrat,'chain',"StopLoss_Long","StopLoss_Short")
# correct
pairStrat <- add.rule(strategy=pairStrat, ...)
pairStrat <- enable.rule(pairStrat,'chain',"StopLoss_Long","StopLoss_Short")
```